# How to solve $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{2k}}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Solution given as

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{2k}}=\frac{((2n)!!)^2}{(2n-1)!!(2n+1)!!}$$

For myself,

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\tbinom{2n}{2k}}
=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{n!}{2n!}\frac{2k!}{k!}\frac{(2n-2k)!}{(n-k)!}
$$

Since
$$
\frac{2n!}{n!}=2^n(2n-1)!!
$$

So

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{2k}}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{2k+1}\frac{(2k-1)!!(2n-2k-1)!!}{(2n-1)!!}
$$

Then I don't know how to forward, agian, what I write above might be a wrong direction.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a two step approach. At first we simplify the binomial identity and then we use generating functions to show OPs identity.
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{2k}}=\frac{((2n)!!)^2}{(2n-1)!!(2n+1)!!}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

**Left-hand side of (1):**  We obtain
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}^2\binom{2n}{2k}^{-1}&=\frac{n!n!}{k!(n-k)!k!(n-k)!}\,\frac{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}{(2n)!}\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{2k}
\end{align*}
The left-hand side can be written as
\begin{align*}
\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

**Right-hand side of (1):**  We obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{((2n)!!)^2}{(2n-1)!!(2n+1)!!}
&=\frac{\left(2^nn!\right)^2(2n)!!(2n)!!}{(2n)!(2n+1)!}\\
&=\frac{\left(2^nn!\right)^4}{(2n)!(2n+1)!}\\
&=\frac{16^n}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-2}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> Using (2) and (3) we can write identity (1) as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=\frac{16^n}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

**A generating function approach:**

The left-hand side of (4) contains the convolution of *[central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)* with generating function
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}z^n
\end{align*}
But the expression (4) has also a denominator $2k+1$ which needs some additional twist.

The following part is the result of an in-depth analysis of an instructive answer to a more general problem **solved by @MarkoRiedel**. His solution can be found via this *[link](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/iadm/Riedel/egorychev.html#gould3.95)*. We continue with a generating function approach and claim the following identity is valid:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{k+q}z^{k+q}=\frac{1}{q}\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\sqrt{1-4z}\sum_{p=q}^{\infty}\binom{2p}{p}z^p}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
We assume $q\geq 1$ is an integer. At the first glance (5) is an astonishing identity and not that obvious. We see both sides start with $z^q$. We also see the coefficient of $z^q$ at the left-hand side is $\frac{1}{q}$ and we use a factor $\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}$ at the right-hand side to assure that the coefficient of $z^q$ is $\frac{1}{q}$. Some connections with (4) which might be useful:

- At the left-hand side is a factor $\frac{1}{k+q}$ which looks to be related somehow with $\frac{1}{2k+1}$ from (4).
- Although there is at the left-hand side not a convolution as in (4), by multiplication with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}$ we come close to it.
- On the other hand we have at the right hand side a reciprocal central binomial coefficient $\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}$ which looks promising.
- The series at the right-hand side is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}$ minus the first $q-1$ terms and multiplied with $\sqrt{1-4z}$.

> **Proof of identity (5):**
>
> We start by differentiating both sides with respect to $z$ and show equality. We obtain from the left-hand side
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{d}{dz}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k+q}\binom{2k}{k}z^{k+q}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}z^{k+q-1}
> \color{blue}{=\frac{z^{q-1}}{\sqrt{1-4z}}}
> \end{align*}
> The right-hand side gives
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{d}{dz}&\left(\frac{1}{q}\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\sqrt{1-4z}\sum_{p=q}^{\infty}\binom{2p}{p}z^p\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{q}\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\sum_{p=q}^{\infty}\binom{2p}{p}z^p
> +\sqrt{1-4z}\sum_{p=q}p\binom{2p}{p}z^{p-1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{q}\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(-2\sum_{p=q}^{\infty}\binom{2p}{p}z^p
> +(1-4z)\sum_{p=q}p\binom{2p}{p}z^{p-1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{q}\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(-2\sum_{p=q}^{\infty}\binom{2p}{p}z^p
> \right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.+\sum_{p=q-1}(p+1)\binom{2p+2}{p+1}z^{p}-4\sum_{p=q}p\binom{2p}{p}z^{p}\right)\tag{6.1}\\
> &=\frac{z^{q-1}}{\sqrt{1-4z}}+\frac{1}{q}\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\sum_{p=q}^{\infty}\left(\underbrace{-2\binom{2p}{p}+(p+1)\binom{2p+2}{p+1}-4p\binom{2p}{p}}_{=0}\right)z^p\tag{6.2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{z^{q-1}}{\sqrt{1-4z}}}
> \end{align*}
> and since the constant terms $0$ in (5) agree the claim (5) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (6.1) we multiply out with $1-4z$ and shift the index of the first sum by $1$ to again have terms with $z^p$.
- In (6.2) we separate the term with $p=q-1$ from the middle sum and put it after simplification as left-most term of the expression.

Now we multiply identity (5) with $\frac{q}{\sqrt{1-4z}}$ and get
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}\frac{q}{k+q}z^{k+q}\tag{7.1}\\
&=\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\sum_{p=q}^{\infty}\binom{2p}{p}z^p\\
&=\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}-\sum_{p=0}^{q-1}\binom{2p}{p}z^p\right)\\
&=\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}-\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\sum_{p=0}^{q-1}\binom{2p}{p}z^p\tag{7.2}
\end{align*}
We use the identity given by (7.1) and (7.2) to come somewhat more close to the wanted identity (4).

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^{n+q}]$ to extract coefficients and obtain from (7.1)
\begin{align*}
[z^{n+q}]&\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{q}{k+q}z^{k+q}\\
&=[z^n]\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{2l}{l}z^l\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}\frac{q}{k+q}z^k\\
&=[z^n]\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2m-2k}{m-k}\frac{q}{k+q}\right)z^m\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\frac{q}{k+q}}\tag{8.1}
\end{align*}
and from (7.2)
\begin{align*}
[z^{n+q}]&\left(\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}-\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\sum_{p=0}^{q-1}\binom{2p}{p}z^p\right)\\
&=[z^{n+q}]\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\binom{2n+2q}{n+q}}\tag{8.2}
\end{align*}

We now have equality of (8.1) and (8.2) for all non-negative integers $q$ of an identity which is pretty close to (5) and in fact even more general as we will see soon.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\frac{q}{k+q}=\binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\binom{2n+2q}{n+q}\tag{9}
\end{align*}

> **A generalised identity:**
>
> We use the common definition of a generalised binomial coefficient $\binom{\alpha}{n}=\frac{1}{n!}\alpha^{\underline{n}}$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and transform the right-hand side of (9) as
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{2q}{q}^{-1}\binom{2n+2q}{n+q}&=\frac{q!q!}{(2q)!}\,\frac{(2q+2n)!}{(q+n)!(q+n)!}\\
> &=\binom{q+n}{n}^{-1}\frac{q!(2q+2n)!}{n!(2q)!(q+n)!}\\
> &=\cdots\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{q+n}{n}^{-1}4^n\binom{q+n-\frac{1}{2}}{n}}\tag{10}
> \end{align*}
>
> Using (10) the identity (9) becomes
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\frac{q}{k+q}=\binom{q+n}{n}^{-1}4^n\binom{q+n-\frac{1}{2}}{n}}\tag{11}
> \end{align*}
>
> We observe we can replace $q$ in (10) with an indeterminate $x$ and transform this identity to get a **polynomial identity**. Since this identity is valid for all non-integral integers, it is valid for all complex values $x\in \mathbb{C}$. So we are allowed to put $q=-\frac{1}{2}$ in (11) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\frac{1}{2k+1}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{k+\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &=\binom{\frac{1}{2}+n}{n}^{-1}4^n\\
> &=\left(\frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdots\frac{3}{2}}{n!}\right)^{-1}\,4^n\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\,\frac{(2n+1)!!}{n!}\right)^{-1}\,4^n\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\,\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^nn!n!}\right)^{-1}\,4^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{16^n}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (4) finally follows.

Comment: Interesting work, (+1). You have seen this identity before, and so did I, it is at this [link](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/iadm/Riedel/egorychev.html#gould3.95) where we set $x=1/2$ to get $2^{2n} {1/2+n\choose n}^{-1}.$

Comment: @epi163sqrt I prefer a direct solution rather than a prooft. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for your instructive solution which enabled me to write a complete answer to this problem.

Comment: @epi163sqrt Genius! You're so proficient in generating function. I've studied it but don't know that we can use it in this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @pkhead: You're welcome! Many thanks for your nice comment. :-)